# Handaling javascript list in php page

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I am working with ajax php  i am having a problem i.e

I am passing a javascript list in a ajax request

```
data: "user_names="+ user_names ;
```

i am getting this list on php page like

```
$participants_names = $_GET['user_names'];
```

and i am trying to iterate that list like

```
   for ($i = 0; $i <= $participants_names; $i++) {
      print $i;
   }
```

but i am not getting the result actualy i am from python and touching this first time in ,php so plz help me out where i am derailing .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$_GET['user_names']` is a string. You can use explode or split php function to make it an array.

If `user_names` is a comma-separated list of names :

```
$participants_names = explode( ',', $_GET['user_names']);
```

Comment: and what about if i use json_encode() to encode that list in json and then iterate ......?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Json is used as an exchange format between client and server. Once the value has arrived on the server there is no reason to encode it to json before processing it.

Comment: ohk actually i was just asking whether it possible or not

Answer (score 1):

I think you can't simply pass a list as a parameter, you should serialize it.
I suggest you to use JSON, which is supported by most browsers.

In JS pass this as parameter

```
"user_names="+JSON.stringify(user_names);
```

and in PHP use this

```
$participants_names = json_decode($_GET['user_names']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Do a...

```
var_dump($participants_names);
```

... and se what it holds. I'm guessing it's something like a comma separeated list?

```
$list = explode(',', $participants_names); // Create an array named $list
for($i = 0; $i <= count($list); $i++) {
    echo $i;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var usernames = ["A", "B", "C"]
data: "user_names="+ user_names.join(",") ; 
$participants_names = explode(",", $_GET['user_names']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try (assuming your user names are split by a semicolon)

```
$arrayUsers = explode(";", $_GET['user_names']);  
foreach($arrayUsers as $user){
   echo $user;
}
```